# Will changing from target=_blank to target=_self affect SEO or analytics?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, html, links

I saw that my website is using `target="_blank"` on internal links due to something I totally missed in the code. So, I changed that to `_self`, as there is no need to target a new window while they are all internal links.

1. Is it (still) okay to use `target=_self`? Will it in any way affect my SEO or performance?
2. Do I need to change something in Google Analytics?

Comment: Its upto you to use _Self or use _target. Both are okay to use.
Thanks.

Comment: You do not need `target=` if you expect the link to be opened in the same window. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you won't see any changes to your SERP positions or indexing regardless of which path you take here, you're doing the right thing by having internal links open in the same tab. (As @closetnoc pointed out above, including the attribute at all is a bit redundant, since the default behavior of links is to open in the same tab, unless otherwise specified.)

Conventionally, webmasters have chosen to open links leading to other websites in a different tab, and links that keep you on the same domain in the same tab. There could be business use cases for opening an internal link in a different tab; for example, event registration funnels or purchase flows. But it doesn't affect SEO, and there's nothing that needs to be adjusted in Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!